# How to create a cross point for two nearby non-crossing edges?

Tags: edit-mode, edges

After some object modifier operations (actually solidify), sometimes it generates edges that should be crossing but actually not, and I want to specify them a crossing point by creating it.

By middle-school geometry, we know that for any two 3D lines that are neither crossing nor parallel, we can always find a third line crossing them and are vertical with both two lines. And I can use the middle point of the third line as the crossing point of the two non-crossing lines. Is there any way to do it in Blender?

The image below shows an example of this situation. The geometries are generated from solidify modifier. The selected lines in orange and white should be crossing, but are actually not, and they are very nearby.
[image: two nearby lines should but not crossing]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you post some screenshots to clarify what you mean?

Comment: I agree with Harry McKenzie. It's a bit confusing since you wrote in the title "a cross point" and in the text "find a third line crossing them". Is it a point or a line what you are looking for?

Comment: I understand this as asking for the shortest line between two skew lines.  This is an interesting problem for me-- I can imagine a couple of sampling based solutions, either make a bunch of points and sample nearest or do a mesh boolean, but that's not as appealing as a non-sampling-- precise!-- solution.  A non-sampling solution would probably involve solving for it mathematically, which you could probably do by doing some googling, but in my opinion, where's the fun if you do that?  The fun for me is in the solving.

Comment: Are you looking to create an operator to do this to, say, 2 selected edges? How do you want to isolate relevant pairs, ignoring the ones you _don't_ want affected?

Comment: @Nathan As I know some computational geometry, actually I can make the mathematical calculation for it, however I don't know how to do it in blender.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie I have attached the screenshot.

Comment: @RobinBetts Yes, I probably need to create a custom plugin that operates on two selected edges, if there aren't existing function for this. I have a few experience on blender plugin ten years ago, and I guess the API has changed a lot.